# Angular js Custom ng-repeat end directive not working with dynamically populating models

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a ng-repeat in a html page which uses a model which gets populated dynamicaly via an api call , .I wrote a custom ng repeat end directive to run some functions  everytime when this model is updated and i rendered in browser,

```
 app.directive('repeatEnd', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if (scope.$last) 
          setTimeout(function(){

         console.log("render completed");
        }, 1);
    };
})
 <li ng-if="compareList.length >= 1" ng-repeat="el in compareList track  by $index" repeat-end>//repeate content//</li>
```

this works for the first time when compareList model is populated dynamically, but when it is populated by another dynamic call, it will not work , it works randomly . Kindly help me get through this issue

Comment: You're only calling the if statement when the directive is linked.  If you want it to run every time the repeat is updated, you'll need a [watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).